# How to determine if character is uppercase, lowercase, digit, or non-alphanumeric without string methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that determines if a character is uppercase, lowercase, digit, or non-alphanumeric without string methods like isupper, islower, isdigit. The program is that everything I enter, it's telling me that its a lower case letter. Can someone help me out?

```
character = input("Enter a character: ")

lowerLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
digits = "0123456789"
lowerCount = 0
upperCount = 0
digitCount = 0
nonAlphaCount = 0

for ch in character:
    for ch in lowerLetters:
        lowerCount += 1
    for ch in upperLetters:
        upperCount += 1
    for ch in digits:
        digitCount += 1
    else:
        nonAlphaCount += 1

if lowerCount > 0:
    print(character, "is a lower case letter.")
elif upperCount > 0:
    print(character, "is an upper case letter.")
elif digitCount > 0:
    print(character, "is a digit.")
elif nonAlphaCount > 0:
    print(character, "is a non-alphanumeric character.")
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that you are doing this: `for ch in lowerLetters:
        lowerCount += 1`. That means that lowerCount is always going to be 26, regardless. You need to compare the lowerLetters with your `ch`.

Comment: The definition of "alphabetic" varies (and "digit" too). Even in English, ASCII letters do not cover the entire vocabulary. Are you interested in ASCII, a subset of alphabetic characters from some language(s), or the full set of Unicode characters defined as alphabetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good (though not the best one for your purpose even without using the methods you mentioned) but you have a couple of typos :) This is what you have:

```
for ch in character:
    for ch in lowerLetters:
        lowerCount += 1
    for ch in upperLetters:
        upperCount += 1
    for ch in digits:
        digitCount += 1
    else:
        nonAlphaCount += 1
```

And this is want you wanted to type:

```
for ch in character:
    if ch in lowerLetters:
        lowerCount += 1
    elif ch in upperLetters:
        upperCount += 1
    elif ch in digits:
        digitCount += 1
    else:
        nonAlphaCount += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Answer (score 4):

You can use ascii value

```
Numbers 0-9 ASCII 48 to 57 
Lowercase letters a-z ASCII 97 to 122 
Uppercase letters A-Z ASCII 65-90
```

use `ord` function. like this:

```
>>ord('a')
97
```

So, to check if `a` is a lowercase letter or not, do:

```
if 97<=ord('a')<=122:
    print "lowercase character"
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You are a genius

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with following part of your code :

```
for ch in character:
    for ch in lowerLetters:
        lowerCount += 1
    for ch in upperLetters:
        upperCount += 1
    for ch in digits:
        digitCount += 1
    else:
        nonAlphaCount += 1
```

You increase the variables without any condition you need to use `all` function for this job :

```
character = input("Enter a character: ")

lowerLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
digits = "0123456789"

if all(ch in character ckafor ch in lowerLetters):
    print(character, "is a lower case letter.")
elif all(ch in character for ch in upperLetters):
    print(character, "is an upper case letter.")
elif all(ch in characterfor ch in digits):
    print(character, "is a digit.")
else:
    print(character, "is a non-alphanumeric character.")
```

Now if you are looking for another way you can use regex for this task but is not as efficient as the preceding solutions.

```
character = input("Enter a character: ")
import re
if re.match(r'[a-z]+',characters):
        print(character, "is a lower case letter.")
elif re.match(r'[A-Z]',characters):
        print(character, "is an upper case letter.")
elif re.match(r'[0-9]+',characters):
        print(character, "is a digit.")
else:
        print(character, "is a non-alphanumeric character.")
```